# How to make XCode bundle C++ project as an .app?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

A few months ago, I inherited a C++ command-line XCode project that I've since turned into an app with a GUI, but XCode won't build it as an .app bundle:

[image: XCode build output]

Instead, XCode builds a Debug folder, which, interestingly enough, works as an app if I copy it and rename it to "[Bundle Display Name].app".

[image]

There are two problems with this though:

(1) I have to manually do this for each build

(2) It doesn't link to my Assets.xcassets file containing my app icons or my Info.plist file or any of the other resources I need.

I've scoured Apple's XCode documentation and come up with nothing. Are there any XCode veterans who know the solution?

**EDIT:** It seems like the only solution is to add a script to the Build Rules to manually change the Debug directory to an .app and structure it properly. The problem I'm now having is that my app doesn't see my .icns file unless the absolute path is hardcoded into the Info.plist file. For example:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon.icns</string>
```

^This doesn't work

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>/Users/.../build/Control Cam.app/Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns</string>
```

^This works. But of course it can't find the icon anymore if I move the app to a different folder. Any ideas how to get it to use relative path names?

Comment: What kind of Xcode target are you building? Xcode requires an App target to build an app bundle (.app file). Choose File > New > Target to add an App target. I haven't built an app bundle using C++ and Make so I don't what else you have to do to get everything building correctly.

Comment: When I try to create a new App target, it gives me two options for the language: Swift and Objective-C. So I don't think that will work. My target has a command-line icon, so I'm assuming it's a command-line target (I didn't originally create the XCode project). It sounds like maybe the only solution is to add a script to the Build Rules to manually change the Debug directory to an .app and structure it properly.